# Scaling elements Upward with Scriptaculous

Tags: javascript, css, events, scriptaculous, prototypejs

I'm building a little menu item using Prototype/Scriptaculous.

The little test I have setup uses Effect.Scale on a menu item. I'd like the item to scale upward and push the other element up with with it when you hover over the menu item.

I have the ul.nav set to a specific height, but the scaled element seems to be positioned absolutely so its removed from the flow and scales downward outside of the box.

Is there a way to do this or am I going about this wrong?
Here is the page:
**DELETED , -invalid URL (http://krd/krd-design.net)**

The CSS:

```
.menuitem {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 90px;
```

}

```
  .lift {
display: block;
background-color: gray;
width: 90px;
height: 1px;
```

}

```
 .nav {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
height: 60px;
```

}

The javascript:

```
$$('.menuitem').each(function(s){
if($(s).down(1).tagName == 'SPAN' && $(s).down(1).className == 'lift') {
    var lift = $(s).down(1);
    $(s).observe('mouseenter', function() {
        new Effect.Scale(lift, 120, {
            scaleX: false,
            scaleY: true,
            scaleContent: false,
            scaleMode: { originalHeight: 100 },
            scaleFrom: 1
        })
    });
}
```

})

Thanks!
Rich

Comment: The URL you posted doesn't work. Please edit or post it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I've always has more success with Effect.Morph, than Effect.Scale. It gives you much finer control.

Comment: While I am using Effect.Scale, looking at Effect.Morph helped me figure out how to set up what I needed.

Setting the nav to a relative position and the li to absolute was the trick.